# openvpn server on router traffic visibility by ISP

Tags: router, openvpn

Can my provider with DPI or another bad guys with SORM with access to all ISP transported traffic read my http packets send over openvpn server running on my router that use ISP connection for internet access.
And maybe someone can show http packet example as ISP will see it on that kind of scheme.

Comment: Off-topic at Server Fault, on-topic at [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking, basically, is "Does a VPN protect my traffic from interception?"

Yes. That's the point of a VPN.

OpenVPN is encapsulating and encrypting your traffic using the TLS protocol. Your encapsulated traffic isn't going to be visible to anyone intercepting the traffic. They're going to see TLS-encrypted data in the payloads they intercept.

Obviously, if the interceptor has access to your key material then they could potentially decrypt your traffic and reveal the contents of the intercepted traffic.